# Button "New branch..." on work item not working anymore

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

The button "New branch..." on work items are not working anymore.

See Image: [image: Work item new branch button not working]

It was working many months before.

On the sprint board the button "New branch..." appears twice. The first one is working as used to, but not the second one.

See image:

[image: Sprint new branch button twice]

Maybe someone has an idea what causes the issue and can lead me in the right direction to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue, tracked here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/WorkItem--Menu---CreateBranch-not-/1441712

All you can do is wait. We have the same issue.

Comment: Ah thank you. Then we have to wait. We uses the "create a branch" link under development group in the work item as a workaround.